# Undoing bash command text deletion

Tags: bash

I use `UP` key to locate a previous command, accidentally deleted last character. Now I'm unable to get back to original command. Pressing `UP` or `DOWN`, the command shown is with last character deleted.

How can I undo this deletion, or to restore the original command?

Comment: If there's only a single character missing, why don't you just type it to add it?

Comment: Press `Ctrl`+`_`.

Comment: @music2myear It was just an example. Using bash mode sometimes a random character is deleted, sometimes a word or part of the command is deleted. Also the immediate reaction to this is "undo" especially when you were reusing a command entered long ago.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you! This is exactly the thing I needed!